# Possible to store encrypted credentials in a PKCS12 keystore?

Tags: java, api, encryption, credentials, pkcs#12

I am trying to find a way I can ensure security of credentials within my system. One requirement is that once the passwords are encrypted I need to be able to provide an API that can be used by both Java and C projects.
One way to achieve this is to have a PKCS12 keystore which works for not just Java (unlike the JKS) but also for other languages.
So the question is can a PKCS12 keystore be used to store encrypted passwords?

Answer (score 0):

No, the PKCS#12 key store cannot be used for passwords. Although officially PKCS#12 allows for personal secrets to be stored in a [`SecretBag`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7292#section-4.2.5) the format of such a bag is not specified. You'll need to define your own key store protocol if you want to store passwords.